# Do Bothans make a physical appearance in Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars

A haunting quote from *Star Wars: Return of the Jedi* is

> "Many Bothans died to bring us this information."

I love how the actress portraying Rebel leader Mon Mothma looks as she delivers this line, as if she is remembering specific individuals that were lost. From what I can remember, this is the only mention of Bothans. I have only watched the films, so I don't know anything about their race beyond this quote. **Do Bothans appear anywhere in the Star Wars films?** Are they depicted in any group shots?

[image]

Comment: For the record, the many Bothans dying part happened in "Shadows of the Empire".

Comment: Wait, all my life I had thought Greedo is a Bothan. What is he then?

Comment: @thegreatjedi He's a [Rodian](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rodian)!

Comment: I hope you people realize than none of the expanded universe novels are canon, thus any race that is unidentified in Star Wars ep 7 is a potential Bothan.

Comment: You can play as a Bothan spy in the original Battlefront II.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, the Bothans first appeared in *[Heir to the Empire](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Bothan#Behind_the_scenes)* and therefore not in any of the movies.

But if you want to know what they look like, here is an image from [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Bothan):

[image]

Answer (score 5):

### Not that we know of

To my knowledge, there are not yet any confirmed Bothans in any *Star Wars* films. This is not likely to change with *Rogue One*, as detailed [here.](http://io9.gizmodo.com/many-bothans-will-not-be-dying-in-rogue-one-1785213325)

**However, we probably do have an idea of what Bothans look like in the new canon.**

In the canon book [*Star Wars Rebels: Sabine My Rebel Sketchbook*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Rebels:_Sabine_My_Rebel_Sketchbook), we see a sketch of a Bothan by Sabine:

[image]

It’s not identified as a Bothan, but it bears such a resemblance to old Legends images of Bothans that it seems likely that that’s what it is.

[image]

Besides, we know that the illustrator [looked up](http://www.theforce.net/story/front/TFN_Interview_Sabine_My_Rebel_Sketchbook_Illustrator_Annie_Stoll_162300.asp) Bothans for the book:

> Even if there wasn’t a canon reference, as an illustrator it is
>   important to find references to draw from whether that’s looking up
>   old creature guides to see what a Bothan might be like or looking in a
>   fashion magazine for cool haircuts.

Answer (score 1):

Bothans do not appear in any of the movies. There is, however, a character that *might* be a Bothan in an episode of the animated series *Star Wars: Droids*. The problem with considering these characters to be Bothans is that Bothan appearance was not established until Timothy Zahn's *Heir to the Empire*, and he even left that a little to the imagination. They would therefore have to be ret-conned as Bothans, which, given the recent changes in canon, is unlikely.

Comment: Just a note to anyone wandering by. @Richard meant "*Heir To The Jedi*", which he linked but confused the title when he wrote the comment. *Heir To The Empire* was the book by Timothy Zahn.

Comment: @phantom42 - thank you from saving me from about 30 minutes of hyperventilating!